# I can send notification by registrationId in NotificationHub Azure?

Tags: c#, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, android-notifications, azure-notificationhub

I need to send push notifications to specific user (Example "Messenger": when I send a message to a client, i will send a notification to alert the user).

I use Azure NotificationHub, and i need send notifications to Android and IOS.

In my research I find nothing concrete to say whether it is possible or not.
I find everything with an associated tag, but can I associate a tag with each user so that I can distinguish all or have a maximum limit?

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-gcm-android-push-to-user-google-notification

Thanks for the help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but can I associate a tag with each user so that I can distinguish all or have a maximum limit?

Of course, you could associate a tag with each user.  We could get more information about [tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-tags-segment-push-message#using-tags-to-target-users) from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-tags-segment-push-message#using-tags-to-target-users). [Registrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management) can be tagged with a tag that contains a user ID.

[image]

The registration also allows multiple tags. We also could use the tag express to handle it.

> or have a maximum limit?

According to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#notification-hub-service-limits), there are limitation on `active devices` and `Tag quota per installation/registration`. No information about the limitation about the registration or tags.

[image]